# Add an Auto increment column that isnt a primary key SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that keeps track of files on a disk. I have the file path set as the primary key since this is the unique piece of data. I want to add a new column that is auto increment but NOT the primary key. Can this be done? I want this column so i can access the data with an id rather than a big long file path string.

```
ALTER TABLE `Media`  ADD `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Comment: As the error states you can't have two AUTO_INCREMENT columns on the same table. You can change your query to give you an incremental id though

Comment: there isnt any auto increment column though. There is a primary key but not an ID column which is what i want.

Comment: You could also drop the Primary Key, add the auto_increment column, then create a unique index on the file path.

Answer (score 4):

Change the table structure so the file path is declared to be `unique` instead of `primary`.  Then add an auto-incrementing primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE `Media` DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (`FilePath`), 
  ADD `ID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);
```

There are advantages to having an integer primary key instead of a string.  For instance, a secondary index will use the primary key to access the row, so having a full file path just makes the index larger than it needs to be.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I added the syntax to do the change you described.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE
        `Media`
ADD     `ID` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted. I agree with the comment above that says to remove the current pk and make the file path the unique. i am under pressure at the moment so i need to just get it working

Comment: It takes less time to do it well than it does to do it twice.

Answer (score -1):

you must insert rows like this :

```
SET @ID = 0;

INSERT INTO Media  (ID,  SomeColumn) VALUES  (@ID := @ID + 1, 'Some Text');
```

Comment: Voted down.  It doesn't address the question and the requirement to get an id and add one to it is a bad idea.  With a busy application, you might get duplicates.